# What is the type of elements of thread_group list in sched.h?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In [sched.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h), task_struct has following 2 fields: thread_group & thread_node. They keep the first element of their list but I could not find which type of variables they contain.

```
1511 struct task_struct {
....
1657         /* PID/PID hash table linkage. */
1658         struct pid_link pids[PIDTYPE_MAX];
1659         struct list_head thread_group;
1660         struct list_head thread_node;
.... 
     }
```

Comment: They are just nodes of the intrusive linked list, they will link the `task_struct`s together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thread_group` and `thread_node` are both intrusive linked-lists of all the threads in a thread group - they are use to link together `task_struct`s, they don't "contain" anything.

The difference between the two is that `thread_group` has its head in the `task_struct` of the thread group leader, whereas `thread_node` has its head in the `signal_struct` shared by the thread group.  In the medium-term `thread_group` is going away.